# Karate DSL: Validating that the response object has a specific key

Tags: karate

The scenario is that I have 2 calls, the first call places an order, and the second call retrieves all orders.

What I am trying to do is first place an order, and second validate that when I retrieve all orders, the new order I placed exists in the orders list.

My issue is with the second call.
The object returned by the second call is the following:

```
{
"44abb823-8450-4c88-b650-9322fb1a3e22":
      {
          "quantity":1, 
          "petId":"a69363f2-de5b-46d7-a0dd-a332c9d6beae",
          "status":"placed"
          },
  "df6bc4d4-b6bb-4550-83c1-421a6c982981":
      {
          "quantity":1, 
          "petId":"d5b4a1d0-22c7-4cca-80e9-52b2f94b809f",
          "status":"placed"
          },
  "fc8b7b76-b3fd-4c5d-8333-94dcfab8a9d3":
      {
          "quantity":1, 
          "petId":"ac06b854-2c51-4e8c-88bd-784f595247eb",
          "status":"placed"
      },
}
```

I wanna validate that the variable orderID which contains of of those object key exists in the list.

I tried:
`* match response contains orderID`
I got: data types don't match (MAP:STRING)

I also tried:

```
* match response == { orderId: '#present' }
```

And I get the following: not equal | actual has 3 more key(s) than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
* def keys = karate.keysOf(response)
* match keys contains 'df6bc4d4-b6bb-4550-83c1-421a6c982981'
```